# How to animate a seaborn's heatmap or correlation matrix?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am relatively new to python (coming from Matlab). As one project, I am trying to create an animated plot of a correlation matrix over time. To make the plots nice, I am trying seaborn. I struggled to get the animation done at all (having issues with Matplotlib backend on a mac), but a very basic animation now works using this code from the web:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

nx = 50
ny = 50

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
im = plt.imshow(data)

def init():
    im.set_data(np.zeros((nx, ny)))

def animate(i):
    #xi = i // ny
    #yi = i % ny
    data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
    im.set_data(data)
    return im

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=50, repeat = False)
```

Now, I was trying to adapt this to `seaborn`, but did not succeed. It seems that seaborn works on subplots and to animate these was far harder. The best thing I got once was a kind of recursive plot, where `seaborn.heatmaps` were plotted on top of each other. Also, the `im.set_data` method was not available.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I replaced `plt.imshow` (casting data via `set_data` didn't work) with `seaborn.heatmap`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
sns.heatmap(data, vmax=.8, square=True)

def init():
      sns.heatmap(np.zeros((10, 10)), vmax=.8, square=True, cbar=False)

def animate(i):
    data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
    sns.heatmap(data, vmax=.8, square=True, cbar=False)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=20, repeat = False)
```

This creates the recursive plot I struggled with.

Comment: think i just found a solution: putting a plt.clf() in the first line of the animate-function works for now! Thanks, Ralf.

Comment: I added your content here as an edit to your question, which is where this actually belongs and edited your answer into an actual answer.

Comment: It doesn't work, since with each iteration your code produce another scale bar on the figure.

Comment: How to make this work in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your answer above, I wanted to do this from a list of dataframes and save as a gif.  So, using your code and Serenity's answer to [Matplotlib animation iterating over list of pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578714/matplotlib-animation-iterating-over-list-of-pandas-dataframes)

```
fig = plt.figure()
def init():
    sns.heatmap(np.zeros((10, 10)), vmax=.8, square=True, cbar=False)

def animate(i):
    data = data_list[i]
    sns.heatmap(data, vmax=.8, square=True, cbar=False)

data_list = []
for j in range(20):
    data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
    data_list.append(data)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=20, repeat = False)

savefile = r"test3.gif"
pillowwriter = animation.PillowWriter(fps=20)
anim.save(savefile, writer=pillowwriter)

plt.show()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: This worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example (tested with Matplotlib 3.0.3).

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


def animate_heat_map():
    fig = plt.figure()

    nx = ny = 20
    data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
    ax = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0, vmax=1)

    def init():
        plt.clf()
        ax = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0, vmax=1)

    def animate(i):
        plt.clf()
        data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
        ax = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=0, vmax=1)

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    animate_heat_map()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of r schmaelzle I created animated seaborn heatmap with annotaion.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


class Heatmap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.anim = None

    def animate(self):
        def init():
            sns.heatmap(np.zeros((10, 10)), vmax=.8, ax=self.ax)

        def animate(i):
            self.ax.texts = []
            sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(10, 10), annot=True, vmax=.8, cbar=False, ax=self.ax)

        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=20, repeat=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hm = Heatmap()
    hm.animate()
```

The trick to update annotations is to make empty `ax.texts = []`.

I hope it will help others! :)