# Celluloid Animated Heatmap Issue with Axes and Missing Plots

Tags: python, pandas, animation, seaborn, celluloid

I am trying to build an animated heatmap using celluloid. The x & y axis and color scale are the same but my code returns the weird output below.

[image]

My code uses seaborn, numpy, pandas, and celluloid and is simplified below:

```
from celluloid import Camera

## Set up celluloid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
camera = Camera(fig)


## Loop to create figures
for item in range(len(df)):
   row = df.iloc[item]
   row = np.array(list(row))

   ## Create df from row
   shape = (8,12)
   df_row = pd.DataFrame(row.reshape(shape))

   ## Build seaborn heatmap
   ax = sns.heatmap(df_row, cmap="Greys", annot=False, vmin=0, vmax=1)
   ax.set_title(item)
   ax.xaxis.tick_top()
   for tick in ax.get_yticklabels():
      tick.set_rotation(0)
   
   ## Snap Celluloid
   camera.snap()

anim = camera.animate(interval=500)
anim.save("animation.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that seaborn constantly creates a new colorbar. To solve it, a fixed `ax` for the colorbar needs to be created at the start of the code.

Here is the general setup, using `celluloid`'s `Camera`. If you leave out `cbar_ax=cbar_ax` you'll see the strange behavior of an endless caravan of colorbars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from celluloid import Camera

fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 9), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})
camera = Camera(fig)

for _ in range(20):
    sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(8, 12), cmap="magma", annot=False, vmin=0, vmax=1,
                ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax)
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelrotation=0)
    camera.snap()

anim = camera.animate(interval=500)
anim.save("animation.mp4")
```

The critical changes to your code would be:

- replace `fig = plt.figure(...)` by `fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(...)`
- call `sns.heatmap` with `ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax`

Comment: Hi JohanC, thank you for the approach. I still seem to be having trouble. This method prints the first heatmap then fails to update at any of the following rows. I would also like to save the animation to a gif or mp4 format. Camera is a part of the celluloid package which is pip installable. Again, I appreciate the approach, but I still seem to be having an issue

Comment: JohanC, your comment in addition to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742845/how-to-animate-a-seaborns-heatmap-or-correlation-matrix were pivotal in hacking together a solution. Thank you!

Comment: I just installed celluloid and updated the answer.  `matplotlib.animation` probably isn't necessary if you use `celluloid`.  `celluloid` looks easier than `matplotlib.animation`  as it doesn't seem to depend on external animation software being properly installed.

Comment: Another option would be to save the index variable for the loop, say as `i`, and then do `heatmap(..., cbar=i == 0)` so you only get one for the first plot.